# tabulatorTables is not defined (version 5)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, svelte, tabulator

[Here's the documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.2/install)

I installed the latest package `5.2.7` like this:

```
npm i tabulator-tables --save
```

I am importing it with this:

```js
import { TabulatorFull as Tabulator } from "tabulator-tables";
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tabulatorTables is not defined at main.js:5:2
```

**main.js**

```js
import App from "./App.svelte";

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
});

export default app;
```

I am doing everything the documentation says. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to not rebuilding the Svelte bundle to include the new code.

```
npm run dev
```